# how to solve lazyinitializationexception not using fetch=FetchType.EAGER?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc, lazy-loading

Iam still getting the exception lazyinitializationexception.
Yes,  i know that it means, that the session is closed while I or something else is trying to access the collection.
No, the OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter did not work.
Yes, @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER) helped but i dont want to use it, cause it will fecth aumotically all the time.

How Else can i do that ?

P.S. : I am using HibernateEntityManger with jpa with annotated class.

UPADATE
here is my code, first of all
I have 4 tables :
users(id,first_name,last_name,email....)
roles(id,name,comment....)
users_roles(user_id,role_id)
mails(id,user_id,subject,message,to_id...)

An user can have mutiples roles ....
Users Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User implements GenericDomain{

    public static final String  _ID = "id";
private Long    id;
private String  firstName;
private String  lastName;
private String  email;  
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>(0);

/* Constructors */  
public User() {
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Long getId() { return this.id; }
public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

@Column(name="FIRST_NAME", nullable = false, length = 64)
@NotEmpty
@Length(min = 4, max = 45)
public String getFirstName() { return this.firstName;   }
public void setFirstName(String firstname) { this.firstName = firstname; }

@Column(name="LAST_NAME", nullable = false, length = 64)
@NotEmpty
@Length(min = 4, max = 45)
public String getLastName() { return this.lastName; }
public void setLastName(String lastname) { this.lastName = lastname; }

@Column(name="EMAIL", unique = false, length = 64)
@Email
@NotEmpty
@Length(min = 4, max = 45)
public String getEmail() { return this.email; }
public void setEmail(String email) { this.email = email; }

@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "USERS_ROLES"
    , joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }
    , inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") }
)
public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return this.roles;
}
public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

/*@Override toString/equals/hascode  */
```

}

Role Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLES")
public class Role implements GenericDomain {
private Long    id;
private String  name;
private String  comment;
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>(0);

public Role() {
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Long getId() { return id; }
public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

@Column(name="NAME", nullable = false, length = 64)
@NotEmpty
@Length(min = 1, max = 32)
public String getName() { return name; }
public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

@Column(name="COMMENT", nullable = true, length = 256)
@Length(min = 0, max = 255)
public String getComment() { return this.comment; }
public void setComment(String comment) { this.comment = comment;}

@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
    name = "USERS_ROLES"
    , joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") }
    , inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }
)
public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return this.users;
}
public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}

/*@Override toString/equals/hascode  */
```

}

mails

@Entity
@Table(name = "mails")
public class Mail implements GenericDomain{

```
private Long    id;
private String  mailSubject;
private String  mailContent;
private Long    receiverId;
private User    user = null;

public Mail(){  
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
public Long getId(){    return this.id; }
public void setId(Long id){ this.id = id;}

@Column(name = "MAILSUBJECT", nullable = false, length = 63)
@Length(max = 63)
public String getMailSubject(){ return this.mailSubject;    }
public void setMailSubject(String mailSubject){ this.mailSubject = mailSubject; }

@Column(name = "MAILCONTENT", nullable = true, length = 255)
@Length(max = 255)
public String getMailContent(){ return this.mailContent;    }
public void setMailContent(String mailContent){ this.mailContent = mailContent; }   

@Column(name = "RECEIVERID")
public Long getReceiverId(){    return this.receiverId; }
public void setReceiverId(Long receiverId){ this.receiverId = receiverId;   }   


@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
@NotNull
public User getUser(){ return this.user;    }
public void setUser(User user){ this.user = user;   }
}
```

user controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/user")
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class UserController {

private UserService userService;
private RoleService roleService;

@Autowired
public UserController(UserService userService, RoleService roleService) {
    this.userService = userService;
    this.roleService = roleService;
}
@RequestMapping(value = "edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editUser(@RequestParam(value="id", required = true) Long id, ModelMap model) {

    model.addAttribute("allRoles", roleService.getAll());
    model.addAttribute("user", userService.getOne(id));
    return "/admin/user/edit";
}    }
```

mail controller

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("mail")
@RequestMapping("/portal/mail")
public class MailController{

@Autowired
private MailService mailService;

@RequestMapping(value = "ajaxLoad", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Mail> list(@RequestParam(value = "type", required = true) String type){
    return mailService.getUserMails((Long) WebHelper.getPrincipal().getUser().getId(),type);
}
```

}

my web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SpringOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SpringOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

my edit.jsp for user

```
<select >
<c:forEach items="${allRoles}" var="role">
    <option value="${role.id}" <c:if test="${fn:contains(roleSelected, role)}">selected="selected"</c:if> >${role.name}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

With all that, i edit.jsp for user is working fine with lazy=false.
With FetchType.EAGER am not able to get any of my mails, am getting into a cycle stackovrflow, without FetchType.EAGER i got that lazy exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

removing all the eager and adding this solve my problem

```
    <mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor">  
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />  
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

the filter didnt work

Answer (score 2):

`OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` and `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` work. You are doing something wrong.

Apart from that, you can use `Hibernate.initialize(..)` to initialize your collections. But doing this manually is not preferred. Give more details of why the filter/interceptor don't work.

**Update:** Instead of mapping the filter to a pattern, map it to the dispatcher servlet. So instead of specifying `<url-pattern>` specfiy `<servlet-name>`.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, check if you really need `Collection` rather than `Set`. If objects within collection are unique, declare variable as `Set`, which solves 90% of issues with `LazyInitializationException`.

Comment: Hi, u have update my post and put some code, i dont use collection as you can see, i use Set, but the lazy exception is still there